# Регистрация/Вход

Tags: html

Если при регистрации, данные отправляются на базу данных, то как сделать вход, слогином и паролем?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже был: [регистрация и авторизация на сайте][1].


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/32990/регистрация-и-авторизация-на-сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код на пхп.

```
<?php
   $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "log", "pass") or die("Сервер mysql выключен, свяжитесь с администрацией");
    mysql_select_db ($db) or die (mysql_error());
     $log = !empty($_POST['login']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) : null;
     $pas = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '$log'";
   $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       if ($row['password'] === $pas) {
          $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
           $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
           $_SESSION['passwd'] = $row['password'];
           $_SESSION['access'] = $row['accessLevel'];
           echo 'ВЫ ВОШЛИ В СИСТЕМУ';
           //обновим последний IP юзера
          mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET lastIP ='$ip' WHERE login = '$log' AND password = '$pas'") or die (mysql_error());
          } else {
          echo "<font color=red>Неправильный пороль</font>";
     }
  } else {
     echo "<font color=red>Не указано Имя</font>";
}
?>
```

Потом проверяешь сессию к примеру `$_SESSION['login']`. К примеру

```
if (!$_SESSION['login']) {
    echo "выводим форму выше";
} else {
    echo "Выводим меню юзера";
}
```